# Is there an equivalent of "var Listener = ListenerRegistration{}" that exists on android and iOS for firebase flutter web?

Tags: flutter, firebase

While pulling firestore data from iOS and Android, we were able to assign listeners to queries and turn them off and on again. Is there a way to do this in Flutter web?

Android example;

```
var Listener = ListenerRegistration{}
Listener =  DB.collection("Database")...
if (Listener != null) {
        Listener.remove()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know about using Firebase in native Android, but this seems to be like a Flutter/Dart `Stream`.

you can say that `Stream` is the thing you can subscribe, to and listen to in order to execute some code and update the state of the Flutter app based on it.

you can get the `Stream` of a collection using the `snapshots()` method like this:

```
Stream collectionSnapshotsStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Database').snapshot();
```

and you can subscribe/unsubscribe from it using a `StreamSubscription`, first  `import 'dart:async'` in your file, then:

```
StreamSubscription subscription = collectionSnapshotsStream.listen((snapshot) {
   // execute something
 });
```

you can turn it off temporarily (pause), with:

```
subscription.pause();
```

and you can turn it on again with:

```
subscription.resume();
```

finally, when you don't need it anymore, you can cancel the whole subscription :

```
subscription.cancel();
```

Comment: This method doesn't work subscription.cancel(); listening continues though

Comment: but on what did you listen, you need to listen on the subscription not the snapshot() in your other code

Comment: this is exactly how i did it strangely the listening continues but it just doesn't update.
i guess this is due to assignment event. first we create a listener then we assign it to subscription. it seems this method just unsubscribe firebase listen event continues in background.